# getting stuck in getInputStream method

Tags: java

I am writing a client  program in java. Server is written in C++. When I am sending message from 
the client to the server it's fine. But during receiving my client thread gets stuck in this call

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

and when I break the connection all the received data gets printed. What I am getting from this scenario is getInputStream() is not getting termination character(which I don't know what it should be), like in c it's null character. So please tell me that what should I append at the end of message at server side to recover form this problem.

Comment: please give feedback before voting negative!!!

Comment: The problem is likely that you're using a buffered reader so it doesn't yield data until a newline is sent.  Try using a non-buffered reader or sending a newline.

Comment: @maerics I have tried using appending a newline at the end but still result is same. can you tell what stream should I use that detects a null at the back ?? I am not aware of java much :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use:

```
in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
```

instead of:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

`BufferedReader` is prepared generally for use with non-network IO (such as file IO) and with plain text where lines are ended with newline character. If you are working with network and binary data (and it seems you do) you should use just plain `InputStreamReader` You can also use some `DataInputStream` or similar to make the reading easier :)